# Reading xls file after resaving

Tags: python, excel

I am downloading an excel file from a website.
If I just use pandas to open the file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('filepath')
```

I get an error `CompDocError: Workbook corruption: seen[2] == 4`

If I resave file before opening it everything works fine

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client

def resave_excel(filename):
    xcl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xcl.workbooks.open(filename)
    xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Save()
    xcl.Quit()

resave_excel('filepath')
df = pd.read_excel('filepath')
```

The problem with this approach is that I actually call Excel application and it is not the safest thing to do, especially if I want to run the full script on some automated basis or if I want to run it on a different platform.

Is there a different approach that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found is discussed on https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/149.

Instead of `pandas` you need to use `xlrd` and make changes to `xlrd/compdoc.py`.